# Requirements error while trying to deploy to Scrapy Cloud

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

I'm trying to deploy my spider to Scrapy Cloud using shub but I keep running into this following error:

```
$ shub deploy
Packing version 2df64a0-master
Deploying to Scrapy Cloud project "164526"
Deploy log last 30 lines:
---> Using cache
---> 55d64858a2f3
Step 11 : RUN mkdir /app/python && chown nobody:nogroup /app/python
---> Using cache
---> 2ae4ff90489a
Step 12 : RUN sudo -u nobody -E PYTHONUSERBASE=$PYTHONUSERBASE pip install --user --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
---> Using cache
---> 51f233d54a01
Step 13 : COPY *.egg /app/
---> e2aa1fc31f89
Removing intermediate container 5f0a6cb53597
Step 14 : RUN if [ -d "/app/addons_eggs" ]; then rm -f /app/*.dash-addon.egg; fi
---> Running in 3a2b2bbc1a73
---> af8905101e32
Removing intermediate container 3a2b2bbc1a73
Step 15 : ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
---> Running in ccffea3009a4
---> b4882513b76e
Removing intermediate container ccffea3009a4
Successfully built b4882513b76e
>>> Checking python dependencies
scrapinghub 1.9.0 has requirement six>=1.10.0, but you have six 1.7.3.
monkeylearn 0.3.5 has requirement requests>=2.8.1, but you have requests 2.3.0.
monkeylearn 0.3.5 has requirement six>=1.10.0, but you have six 1.7.3.
hubstorage 0.23.6 has requirement six>=1.10.0, but you have six 1.7.3.
Warning: Pip checks failed, please fix the conflicts.
Process terminated with exit code 1, signal None, status=0x0100
{"message": "Dependencies check exit code: 193", "details": "Pip checks failed, please fix the conflicts", "error": "requirements_error"}
{"message": "Requirements error", "status": "error"}
Deploy log location: /var/folders/w0/5w7rddxn28l2ywk5m6jwp7380000gn/T/shub_deploy_xi_w3xx8.log
Error: Deploy failed: b'{"message": "Requirements error", "status": "error"}'
```

It looks like a simple problem of an outdated package (six). However the installed package actually IS up to date:

```
$ pip show six
Name: six
Version: 1.10.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

I'm running python 3.6 through pyenv on a Mac.
Any ideas?

EDIT:

my `requirements.txt` file only contains the following dependency:

```
newspaper==0.0.9.8
```

EDIT 2: `scrapinghub.yml`

```
projects:
  default: 164526
requirements_file: requirements.txt
```

Thanks,
Simon!

Comment: `six==1.10.0` is the version you have in your local system, not the one deployed. Are you correctly specifying the requirements file in `scrapinghub.yml`? Would you mind pasting the contents of your requirements file?

Comment: I added the requirements file to the question. Adding six==1.10.0 to it throws `newspaper 0.0.9.8 has requirement six==1.7.3, but you have six 1.10.0.` and `monkeylearn 0.3.5 has requirement requests>=2.8.1, but you have requests 2.3.0.`

Comment: Could you paste the contents of the `scrapinghub.yml` file? In particular the `requirements_file` and `stacks` keys.

Comment: Added `scrapinghub.yml` to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this (with help from scrapinghub's support forum) by adding the following code to `scrapinghub.yml`:

```
stacks:
  default: scrapy:1.3-py3
```

and changing `requirements.txt` to use the python3 branch of `newspaper`:

```
newspaper3k==0.1.9
```